# Windows phone 8 Textbox accept return as submit button

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, textbox, event-handling

In my app I have a textbox and when the user presses the return button on the keyboard it should act has a event for the textbox. Similar to if a user pressed a submit button.

```
<TextBox Name="textBox1" Grid.Row="0" Text="Search or Type URL" Background="White" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Margin="62,0,125,0" Foreground="#FF6E6E6E" AcceptsReturn="True" />
```

Above is the XAML for the textbox, and the `AcceptsReturn` is set to true.

Do I add a return event handler?

Thank you in advance :)

If you need any more details please comment and I will be happy to explain in further detail :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you can do is handle the KeyDown event like this:

```
private void SomeTextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Key == Key.Enter)
    {
         this.Focus(); // dismiss the keyboard
         // Call the submit method here
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** *AcceptsReturn* means that when Return/Enter is pressed on the keyboard, it will add a newline/Return character, and not dismiss the keyboard.